# Как запустить тег <video> в нужный момент?

Tags: jquery

контролера не должно быть видно просто видео без всяких кнопок и полосок. Запускается к примеру через 10 секунд после запуска страницы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

У HTMLVideoElement есть метод play(). Просто устанавливаете таймер в теге `<script></script>`. [0] - найдет первый элемент с классом `.video`, поэтому если планируете их несколько, то нужно будет обращаться по id или же сделайте другой класс.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $(".video")[0].play();
}, 10000);
```